# MySQL #1064: declare a variable

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need to declare the variable in MySQL. and here is what I have till now.

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd
BEFORE UPDATE ON chats FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT name FROM messages;
END
```

logically, it seams OK. but there is a strange error
i.e

**SQL query:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd
    BEFORE UPDATE ON chats FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT name FROM messages;
```

**MySQL said:**

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4
```

Comment: need to change your delimeters. eg. `delimiter $$` and remember to add `end $$` and restore default delimiter

Comment: now it says `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$$' at line 5`

Comment: create a fiddle with the table definition and trigger. also please confirm if you are using mysql or oracle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works. Will gladly delete it when it gets dupe closed.

It merely lacks a delimiter wrapping block.

```
drop trigger if exists upd;

delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER upd
BEFORE UPDATE ON chats FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE vapenid INT;
END;
$$
delimiter ;
```